# How to use Resources.LoadAll<T>() to get derived classes

Tags: unity, c#, assets

EDIT: Unity's Resources.LoadAll() does include all derived types. My mistake!

I noticed that the type filter in Unity's Resources.LoadAll() filters out only classes of type T. I would prefer it to include all derived types of T as well. Is there a good function to also get the derived types, or should I use reflection, or should I hard code two arrays and join them together? For reference, I only have one type derived from T right now, but it may expand to several later.

See:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html

Comment: When you say "filter out" you actually mean, "include"? Are you so sure that derived types aren't loaded?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Sorry I made a mistake. Derived types are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry, I made a mistake! Because I made wrapper classes, I forgot to derive one wrapper class from another. The Resources.LoadAll function does in fact find all derived types.